# Find a part duplicates of line text file and print all line duplicate - python

Tags: python-3.x

I try to find a apart duplicate and print all that line. my code current always print miss 1 line. how can i fix this. thanks!

My code

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    seen = set()
    for line in f:
        line_lower = line[:3].lower()
        if line_lower in seen:
            print(line)
        else:
            seen.add(line_lower)
```

file.txt

```
abcdef
quopjsl
abcasx
qdxms
abcsdc
```

Current result:

```
abcasx
abcsdc
```

Expect result:

```
abcdef
abcasx
abcsdc
```

Comment: what does this mean "a apart duplicate"....  do you mean a part duplicate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good attempt, but the list fails because the first line is never accounted for. (You could recheck the first line with, but this would be cumbersome).

So, this is best done with a `dict` which is both quicker and cleaner.

The strategy is to:

- read the data into the dict as a list
- assign the first 3 characters to the keys of the dict.

so this works.

```py
with open('some_file.txt') as f:
    
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        # read data ignoring carriage return
        data = line[:-1]

        # first three letters
        first_three = line[:3].lower()

        # append occurances
        if first_three in d:
            d[first_three].append(data)
        else:
            d[first_three] = [data]


# print things that occur more than once
for v in d.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print(v)
```

returns this:

```
['abcdef', 'abcasx', 'abcsdc']
```